# Making a 'master thread' for bugs and workarounds for Ubuntu 15.04 issues and bugs?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, bug-reports

What does everyone think if we get a single thread going for bugs and workarounds for people with issues relating to 15.04 install. Maybe a wiki type thread. I'm sure a lot of people are coming here for answers and are probably having issues finding them due to lots of disparate threads. I know Nvidia issues alone have about 5 workarounds, I finally after about 6 hours was able to get back in LOL it's frustrating and would not want to wish this on anyone

Also as an aside this will likely drop the amount of duplicate questions

Comment: This is what release notes are for, almost every similar thread on the Ubuntu forms ever essentially re-quotes the release notes with potential work arounds. As problems and answers change over time, IMO askubuntu is not the best format for such a discussion.

Answer (score 8):

This suggestion is ultimately in conflict with the actual purpose of the site and the guidelines and regulations/rules within the Help Center.

Here's the big considerations:

- Bugs are still offtopic here regardless (this is detailed in the Help Center).  Even if we have a workaround, the sheer number of bugs that can happen makes it unfeasible to maintain a master list for this.  We could in theory have one master thread for each bug that has a workaround, however the idea is to ***discourage*** the posting of bugs in any way shape or form and instead file the bug on Launchpad - if it's a duplicate of another bug that has a workaround on it, triagers or the apport retracers will find it.
- List type questions and answers are a bad fit and actually against the site scope (per the Help Center).  This has always been the case, the only reason the older 'software recommendation' posts with lists of potential alternatives exist is because they have some use, although we still discourage such types of questions/answers.
- Dupe voting works fine to ID duplicate questions, and that's actually what should be done. (this is still the primary moderation method for handling duplicates)
- Consider the [Canonical "wifi not working" question proposal here on meta](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/13726/10616), and the many issues that come with such 'master' posts for general issues related to hardware related problems and bugs, which would apply here too:

  - If we have the same workarounds for an NVIDIA card then we could have one master question for NVIDIA, but given there are a ton of NVIDIA cards that is not feasible.
  - Same logic applies for AMD graphics cards, and the following (this is not an all inclusive list):

    1. wifi cards from multiple manufacturers
    2. Ethernet cards from multiple manufacturers
    3. Sound cards from various manufacturers
    4. ... (an infinite list of potential similar situations)

We can't create a master post for those or linking to the masters because we end up with either a billion pages of support answers or an unending list.  It's not feasible.